# audio won't stop when closing html5 modal with embedded video

Tags: css, html, modal-dialog, vimeo

I have a vimeo video embedded in a modal. It's simple code and I think it's just show/hide, so even tho the video is gone, the audio keeps playing -But I'm not sure.  the modal works and the close button works, but voice over keeps on.  New to modals - could really use some help.  thanks.  Here's the code

CSS

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 600px;
    height:400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    audio: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#openModal">
    <img src="img/video-play.png" width="125" height="125">
</a></h2>          

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/14266818" width="600"
     height="400px" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen    
     allowfullscreen></iframe> 
</div></div>
```

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle with a working example? When a user clicks "close" what are you having it do?

Comment: It closes the modal window. The modal and the video close but the audio continues on.... sigh

Answer (score 0):

I have a vimeo in a modal as well and I used the following script to turn off the movie completely when "x"ing out of the modal.

```
$('#videoToggleOff').click(function(){
    $('iframe#myVideo').attr('src',''); 
    $('iframe#myVideo').attr('src','your vimeo link here');
});
```

HTML

Modal Exit Button

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" id="videoToggleOff"><h4 class="videoText">X</h4></button>
```

iframe in modal

```
<iframe id="myVideo" src='your vimeo link' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

The script basically removes the video when exit is clicked but then reset the URL so if the user clicks play again its not broken.

Comment: Either I'm doing something wrong or unfortunately, this didn't work - The new button isn't closing the modal, and even with video paused, the audio still keeps on playing. Thanks for helping -if you can think of any reason the button wouldn't close the modal, happy to hear it.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap along with Bootstrap.js which has the JQuery in it to control a modal.  If you are not using bootstrap and using some other JS to control your modal you would need to update the close modal button code to work with your script.